# Does charging any electrical device in exterme temparature affect the current flow?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons

Recently in an Electric vehicle(EV) charging station, the charging time to charge a particular vehicle was 1 Hour (18V capacity of battery), but now in temperatures beyond 40 Degree Celsius, it is taking approximately 3 Hours. EV has a proper management system which controls its temperature, but not sure of the charging point or adapter, I need to find the root cause of the problem and where is it starting from.

Answer (score 0):

This may well be the car limiting the charge rate due to the battery temperature rising through the charging process. This is also to do with the battery chemistry...

Find somewhere cooler to charge it so the battery can keep itself cool. If that is not possible, then you have to wait for it to charge or accept a partial charge.

Comment: can I design something which can cool down the charging adapter and socket with which it is connected to?